# CMake is unable to find SFML directories in Windows when creating a simple project

Tags: c++, windows, cmake, sfml

I recently downloaded CMake for Windows, since I wanted to develop a cross-platform plugin for SFML, and decided to test out how to do so by following a guide, which is [here](https://blog.beuc.net/posts/Build_a_SFML_project_with_CMake/). As per the guide, I created a folder in my Documents directory called `sfml_test_cmake` (Windows 10) with a `CMakeLists.txt`, `main.cpp` (which has the SFML code), and a folder `cmake_modules` which would hold a file [FindSFML.cmake](https://github.com/SFML/SFML/blob/master/cmake/Modules/FindSFML.cmake). The `CMakeLists.txt` looks as follows:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.9)
project(SFML-CmakeTest)

set(EXECUTABLE_NAME "sfml_test_cmake")

add_executable(${EXECUTABLE_NAME} main.cpp)

set(CMAKE_MODULE_PATH "${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/cmake_modules" ${CMAKE_MODULE_PATH})
find_package(SFML 2.4 REQUIRED system window graphics network audio)
target_link_libraries(${EXECUTABLE_NAME} ${SFML_LIBRARIES})

install(TARGETS ${EXECUTABLE_NAME} DESTINATION bin)
```

and the `main.cpp`, which is a simple test program looks as follows:

```
#include <SFML/Graphics.hpp>

int main()
{
    sf::RenderWindow testWindow{ sf::VideoMode{ 640, 480 }, "Test Window", sf::Style::Default };

    while (testWindow.isOpen())
    {
        sf::Event winEvent;
        while (testWindow.pollEvent(winEvent))
        {
            if (winEvent.type == sf::Event::Closed)
            {
                testWindow.close();
            }
        }
        testWindow.clear();
        testWindow.display();
    }
}
```

As for where SFML is installed, it is installed in both my Documents directory, and my `C:\` drive. To finally build the code, I opened `cmd.exe`, created a new directory inside my folder for the build, and ran `cmake ..`. The errors I got were:

```
CMake Error at cmake_modules/FindSFML.cmake:357 (message):
  Could NOT find SFML (missing: SFML_SYSTEM_LIBRARY SFML_WINDOW_LIBRARY
  SFML_GRAPHICS_LIBRARY SFML_NETWORK_LIBRARY SFML_AUDIO_LIBRARY)
```

Upon looking in `FindSFML.cmake`, I found this:

```
# define the list of search paths for headers and libraries
set(FIND_SFML_PATHS
    ${SFML_ROOT}
    $ENV{SFML_ROOT}
    ~/Library/Frameworks
    /Library/Frameworks
    /usr/local
    /usr
    /sw
    /opt/local
    /opt/csw
    /opt)
```

Which tells my that Cmake is only searching in the directories it SFML would be in if I was on Linux, explaining why the directories couldn't be found. To fix the problem, I changed the function to the following:

```
# define the list of search paths for headers and libraries
set(FIND_SFML_PATHS
    ${SFML_ROOT}
    $ENV{SFML_ROOT}
    ~/Library/Frameworks
    /Library/Frameworks
    /usr/local
    /usr
    /sw
    /opt/local
    /opt/csw
    /opt
    C:/)
```

However, this time rebuilding resulted in the same error, leaving my confused. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do not modify the original FindSFML.cmake. Instead, define a variable [CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.3/variable/CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH.html) which contains the paths, where SFML installed on your computer should be. Adding "C:\" to the list of searched paths would not work, cmake won't search recursively all directories in the specified path.

Comment: However, I am getting another error, this time in the built solution. I ran the CMake as follows: `cmake .. -DCMAKE_PREFIX_PATH=C:/SFML-2.4.2`. When I build the solution however, I get the error `Cannot open include file SFML/Graphics.hpp`: No such file or directory`. Your answer is correct nonetheless.

Comment: You should add ```target_include_directories(${EXECUTABLE_NAME} ${SFML_INCUDE_DIR})``` command in your cmake..

Comment: That doesn't work. I get an error, Incorrect amount of arguments passed to `target_include_directories`. Looking at the documentation, I see that it should probably be just `include_directories`, although I am unsure. Now the code builds but I get the same error as my second comment.

Comment: ```target_include_directories``` and ```include_directories``` are different commands. You might achieve your goal with the latter, but I think ```target_include_directories``` is recommended here. Have a look at the docs: https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.3/command/target_include_directories.html

Comment: Im still unsure what the command would be. (I'm very new to this)